# Selenium stepcounter (count the "driver." calls)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, event-listener

I want to make it easier for my colleques to check for themselvs which Teststep let the test fail. Till now they just copy their recorded steps (with Selenium IDE) into a testclass. Right now I wrote a logger method to get the stepcount and the current time. But they have to call the method between each step.
Another way would be to transform every step into a method and call them, so TestNG will give me a nice report. But that would mean that the Transcript-Effort (driver.findE... to Method) after the recording with IDE is quite high. Is there another way to track which step did fail? Is it possible to do so with Event-listener and handler? Till now just a counter (output just a number) would be nice. 
Thanks in advance 
Arno

Comment: This is a pretty broad question with solutions ranging from somewhat simple to very complex. Your best bet is to just do whatever is the most simple thing you can think of to do what you want, and go from there.

Comment: @mrfreester I think this is a very specific question and sometimes it is better to search for the best way not for the easiest. The easiest is discribed above (Loggermethod) but it is not efficient.